# What is the semantic relationship between the verbal phrases of a serial verb construction?

Tags: grammar, syntax, verbs

The general syntax of a serial verb construction sentence type is:

> S **VP1** **VP2** **VP3**...

wherein S stands for Subject and VP for verbal phrase.

As far as I know, the sequence of verbal phrases express an event in a detailed way.

But is the relationship between the verbal phrases just temporal, i.e. do the verbal phrases describe an event temporally in the sequence of their appearance?

For example:

> 我 看水果 切水果 愉快地吃水果 .
>
> I see a watermelon,then cut it, then joyously eat it.

Is the temporal relationship the only one?

Comment: cf.＂外国人实用现代汉语语法＂二、连动句中前后两个谓语动词的关系（一）后一动词表示前一动词的目的。例如：我去寄信。他去‌​南京旅行。两个谓语动词都可以带宾语。例如‌​：同学们进城看杂技了。我们找他谈重要的事‌​情。（二）前一动词及其宾语表示后一动词的‌​手段、方式。例如：他用左手写。我坐飞机去‌​。她们坐飞机去广东。我们用汉语谈话。（三‌​）后一动词表示前一动词的目的，而前一动词‌​的宾语在意义上也是后一动词的动作对象。前‌​一动词要带宾语，后一动词一般不带宾语。例‌​如：我倒水喝。他买衣服穿。我们自己做饭吃‌​。他要你的设计图看看。（四）前一动词是＂‌​有＂，后一动词常是补充说明＂有＂的宾语的‌​用途的；＂有＂的宾语在意义上也是后一动词‌​的动作对象。前一动词要带宾语，后一动词带‌​不带宾语都可以。例如；我有笔用。他们都有‌​报纸看。我们有新项目要研究。我有几个问题‌​问老师。我每天都有时间锻炼身体。今天老师‌​没有参考发给大家。 "Temporal relationship" may only be a consequence of the required relationships outlined above.

Comment: Thus 看水果 切水果 愉快地吃水果 does not seem to be a 连动句,（serial verb construction, in fact 连词 like 而 and abverbs like 就 are needed，in which case it is not a 连动句。

Comment: Maybe in view of answer below note that "verbal construction in series" = 连动句 is the technical term used in Chinese grammar involving purpose,means or manner relationships between the V-O phrases involved (as quoted above).

Answer (score 2):

> Is the temporal relationship the only one?

Most, but not all.

"我看水果"，"我切水果" and "我愉快地吃水果" are three separate SVO sentences. When we consolidate them into a single sentence, the temporal relationship between each verb phrase is there because these verb phrase must follow a logical timeline.

> 我看(到)水果(就)切开它们(然后)愉快地吃 - Once I saw the fruit, I cut it and then happily ate it ,

*I must see the fruit first, before I can cut it, and I must cut it first, before I can eat it.*

Similarly:

> 我大喝一聲, 我揮拳, 我打中他小腹 - I shout, I punch, I hit his lower abdomen
>
> 我大喝一聲(便)揮拳打中他小腹 - I shouted and immediately punch and hit his lower abdomen

*I shouted first, then I punch, and finally hit his abdomen*

However, not all multiple verb phrase has a temporal relationship like the examples above. They can happen concurrently.

Example:

> 我吃飯，我看電視，我大聲笑
>
> I have dinner, I watch TV., I laugh loudly
>
> 我吃飯(的同時)(邊)看電視(邊)大聲笑
>
> I laugh loudly while I am watching TV. and having dinner.

*I have dinner, watch TV and laugh loudly at the same time.*